# capistrano 3 `rake db:migrate` runs anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

My rails application uses capistrano 3.4.0 for the deploy tasks.
In my Capfile I have the line `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` in order to have the configured task that can run the DB migrations.
When I `cap production deploy`, I can see always the following output:

```
INFO [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
DEBUG [6214167f] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d XXXX/releases/20160117093811; then echo "Directory does not exist 'XXXX/releases/20160117093811'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@candiru-web
DEBUG [6214167f] Command: if test ! -d XXXX/releases/20160117093811; then echo "Directory does not exist 'XXXX/releases/20160117093811'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [6214167f] Finished in 0.005 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1ebeb8c8] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate as deploy@candiru-web
DEBUG [1ebeb8c8] Command: cd XXXX/releases/20160117093811 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
```

even if I don't add something like `after :deploy, "deploy:migrate"`.

If I comment out the line `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'`, the migration won't be executed.

Why? shouldn't it run only if I add the task to my deploy script in `config/deploy.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation of the [capistrano/rails](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/) gem, you have to set `:conditionally_migrate` option in order to check if you need to run migrations.

I guess that's the option you need and you should add it in your `deploy.rb`, this way:

```
set :conditionally_migrate, true
```

---

And to answer your question, in [`migrations.rake`](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake#L30) file the task `deploy:migrate` is already set to run after `deploy:updated`.

Also, if you want to completely remove this task from your deploy process, and always run migrations manually, by invoking `deploy:migrate`, you can do like this:

```
Rake::Task["deploy:migrate"].clear_actions
```